# How can I stop Spyne from wrapping arguments in a complexType?

Tags: c#, python, soap, spyne

I'm trying to use Spyne to provide web services from Python. I have everything working for a test function called SayHello(name, times). However, I'm wondering why Spyne wraps the name and times arguments in a complexType called SayHello? This makes consuming the web service in .NET much more cludgey (i.e. instead of `appClient.SayHello("Dave", 5)` I have to do `SayHello args = new SayHello(); args.name = "Dave"; args.times = "5"; appClient.SayHello(args);` which is very inelegant).

Is there a way to force Spyne not to wrap arguments in a complexType?

Here's the relevant portion of the current wsdl that Spyne generates:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="solutions.sfcs" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:complexType name="SayHello">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element name="times" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `_body_style='bare'` to the `@rpc` decorator to prevent that wrapping. But you'll most likely get:

```
Exception: body_style='bare' can handle at most one function argument.
```

If you can fix this in a way that doesn't break other tests, I can merge your patch.

Comment: if YOU can fix this in a way that doesn't break other tests I'll give you this 50 pt bounty :)

Comment: On a related note, I wonder if it has anything to do with the documentation being opposite the implementation? Comments on the `rpc` method in `decorators.py` say `soap_body_style=rpc`->`body_style = bare`, but the implementation is actually `soap_body_style=rpc`->`body_style = wrapped`

Comment: unfortunately, just changing that doesn't seem to fix the issue.